# Is there a way to connect redmine comment with git commit

Tags: git, redmine

When using redmine with svn repo, in issue comments you can use rXXX in comment message, to create link to Revision XXX.
Is there a way to make same thing with git repo, where revision Id looks like "e013ae90" (short id)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The directions for this are in [Redmine's text formatting page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineTextFormatting).

> Redmine allows hyperlinking between issues, changesets and wiki pages from anywhere wiki formatting is used.
>
> - ...
> - Link to a changeset with a non-numeric hash: **commit:c6f4d0fd** (displays c6f4d0fd). Added in r1236.